# Google API for onhub

Tags: api, packet, sniffing

I'm trying to create an API for the Google Onhub router, but when I sniff my phone's (as google requires an app to control their router which is why I am making this API to be able to control the router via web interface) network traffic it doesn't send to the router but to a google server IP and when I try to connect to the IP I timeout, any ideas on how I could figure out how to connect/send packets to the google server?

Comment: I am documenting this API. You can read the beta documentation [here.](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/7490211/SzzdD1pF?version=latest) What you are looking for is the 'Google Home Foyer' API, and it is a private service used exclusively by Google's apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OnHub is managed via the standard GoogleAPI.

The scope required for the OnHub is:  `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/connectedhome.onhub`, but this is undocumented. If you request an access_token with the previous scope, you can guess endpoints required for API communications.

I am working on a project for this now and will be writing a blog post once completed with more details.

Comment: Did you ever write a blog post? very interested in getting information about connected devices for a project I'm working on.

Comment: Can you give us more info about how you "guess" the endpoints? I tried `https://googlehomefoyer-pa.googleapis.com/v2` -> the endpoint that the app is using, but this needs other scopes.